Converting a flat file into JSON structure using ADF (Azure Data Factory)
I have a flat file which contains information such as names, addresses, mobile numbers, email addresses, etc. We want to convert this into a JSON-structured output. I have created a data flow which is producing the below output (this is not valid json)
Flow:-

Logic:-

'{
"Name": "Test Customer 1",
"Id": 2,
"to_AddressIndependentMobile": [
{
"result": {
"MobilePhoneNumber": "010-1100-111"
}
}
]
}
'

However I need slight changes in output like below
'{
"Name": "Test Famouns London Imaging Center",
"Id": 2,
"to_AddressIndependentMobile": {
"results": [
{
"Contact": "010-1100-111"
}
]
}
}'
Need help on this.
Expected Output


Can you provide your input data i.e, source data preview for the above expected output?

@RakeshGovindula,
Input:
id,Name,contact
2,Test Customer,123-3456-987
Expected Output:
{
"Name": "Test Customer",
"Id": 2,
"to_AddressIndependentMobile": {
"results": [
{
"Contact": "123-3456-987"
}
]
}
}

You can use the below expression to the to_AddressIndependentMobile column in the derived column to achieve your requirement.
@(results=[@(contact=contact)])


You can see it's giving the expected JSON structure. You can remove extra contact column using select transformation after this.

Result in JSON file:


Thanks for your reply, Rakesh, I had used similar logic, I have 10 columns out of that I need to take only few hence hence I used aggr.
All are individual records which may not be consumable to Target system. Is there any way to generate single file separated by coma ?

You can remove the extra columns by using select transformation. And coming to single file, In the sink use csv file and go to sink settings-> Output to single file -> and give your file name. For sample, I have used it to generate a single JSON file https://i.imgur.com/egOxZSp.png

thanks, now all the records are coming as individual records? Is there any way to merrge the records so that will help to load data in bulk.

For that, you need to group by and use the above expression in the aggregate expression itself. It groups the similar rows and creates the array of those.

when I am doing the group by then for one extra bracket does come which is not require to_AddressIndependentMobile: [ { result: {} } ] likje this.
